# Projecting a planar model over a cylinder

Tags: geometry

I'm looking at how to take a set of coordinates and map them around a cylinder. I'm looking for a starting point on the correct terms and equations that will be needed to achieve this transform.  If I'm pointed to secondary references, I'll come back to the question with updates.

For example, I'd like to take the 3d coordinates for the some block letters - "TEXT" and project that around a cylinder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks David for inlining.

Answer (score 3):

Most 3D softwares can do this through bending modifiers. Using the diffeomorphism
$$ \boldsymbol\varphi \begin{bmatrix} \rho\\\phi\\z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\rho\cos\phi \\ \rho\sin\phi \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You can try putting your text into the rectangular region $[0,\infty[ \times [0,2\pi[ \times \mathbb{R}$ and transform it using the above diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to this from first principles so looking for a deeper understanding of just the maths.   I'll research the information you have posted to understand that deeper.

Answer (score 1):

[Cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) furnish one natural strategy. If your letters live in Cartesian space with coordinates $(r, \theta, w)$, map them to Cartesian coordinates
$$
(x, y, z) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, w).
$$

Comment: That was the direction that I was expecting to go - from the Cartesian coordinates to cylindrical and then recalculate the Cartesian coordinates.  I'll wait for a few more answers and summarize my findings.  I was hoping for a direct translation of x->x' without having to determine θ, but I'll keep brushing up on my geometry.

Comment: In case it matters, you don't have to determine $\theta$; it's the horizontal (left-right) coordinate of your lettering. Similarly, $w$ is the vertical (up-down) coordinate of your lettering, and $r$ is "depth" measured perpendicularly to the plane containing your text.